# What is the correct way to write PATH variable in Docker ENV instruction?

Tags: docker

I have tried to build a docker image and found that the PATH variable I set has some issues. A Minimal non-working example is:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-cu"]
ARG CTAGS_DIR=/root/tools/ctags

 # Install common dev tools
RUN apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated \
  && apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y git curl autoconf pkg-config zsh

# Compile ctags
RUN cd /tmp \
  && git clone https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags.git \
  && cd ctags \
  && ./autogen.sh \
  && ./configure --prefix=${CTAGS_DIR} \
  && make -j$(nproc) \
  && make install \
  && rm -rf /tmp/ctags
ENV PATH=$HOME/tools/ctags/bin:$PATH

RUN echo "PATH is $PATH"
RUN which ctags
```

In the above Dockerfile, the line `ENV PATH=$HOME/tools/ctags/bin:$PATH` does not work as expected. It seems that `$HOME` is not correctly expanded. The following two instructions also do not work:

```
ENV PATH=~/tools/ctags/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH="~/tools/ctags/bin:$PATH"
```

Only settings the absolute path works:

```
# the following setting works.
ENV PATH="/root/tools/ctags/bin:$PATH"
```

I have looked up the docker references but can not find document about this.

Comment: Which `$HOME` do you expect Docker to use there?

Comment: `/root` since `echo $HOME` inside the container shows `/root`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you're building a Docker image, it's okay to install things into the normal "system" directories.  Whatever you're building will be isolated inside the image, and it can't conflict with other tools.

The easiest answer to your immediate question is to arrange things so you don't need to set `$PATH`.

In the example you give, you can safely use Autoconf's default installation directory of `/usr/local`.  That will almost certainly be empty when you start your image build and only things you install will be there.

```
RUN ... \
 && ./configure \
 && make \
 && make install
```

(The Python corollary is to not create a virtual environment for your application; just use the system `pip` to install things into the default Python library directories.)

Don't expect there to be a home directory.  If you have to install in some non-default place, `/app` is common, and `/opt/whatever` is consistent with non-Docker Linux practice.  Avoid `$HOME` or `~`, they aren't generally well-defined in Docker (unless you go out of your way to make them be).

Comment: Sometimes, I have to set PATH since I installed some application which I do not want to put in /usr/local.